# Is there an email client optimized for screen readers and accessiblity?

Tags: linux, gnome, accessibility

I'm currently working on a project to help visually impaired people. We're planning to use [Orca screen reader](http://projects.gnome.org/orca/) for gnome. Everything is doing great but there is a problem with email  web clients the most popular ones(gmail, yahoo, hotmail) are not optimized for screen readers. Is there some kind of simple email client optimized for this? Need to be very simple and straight foward and support multiple users too.

Answer (score 1):

There is application list for software supported by Orca:
http://live.gnome.org/Orca/AccessibleApps

As you can see Evoultion (mail client for gnome) is supported. Evolution is easy to use mail client and it can be configured easy. Maybe you can check it out.

The other popular and supported app is Thunderbird that is easy to use (account setup is uber simple).

Answer (score 1):

Text-based e-mail clients could be a way too. Since gnome-terminal is well supported by orca, you could try mutt or alpine.
Braille and mutt seem to work together well: [mailing list thread](http://osdir.com/ml/redhat.blinux.general/2002-09/msg00043.html)

Answer (score 1):

The blind person on my team uses Emacs with the VM mail-reader to access Gmail via IMAP.  That ties into a braille-augmented keyboard.